# Banner Image Zooms in on Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, static-pages

I have a static html page https://www.poggenamp.com with a mobile version. The mobile manner appears zoomed in, and I am not sure how to fix it. Checking through Chrome's Inspector as well as my iPhone 13 Pro. I have added my CSS code that is applied to the banner and removed the rest.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1140px
    }

    .banner:after {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .buttonmain {
        padding: 12px 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .banner {
        padding: 60px 0 120px;
    }

    .banner .title {
        font-size: 36px;
        line-height: 44px;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .banner .title {
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 38px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .banner {
            padding: 60px 0 130px;
        }

        .banner:after {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
            background: url(../images/MobileBannerPANG.jpg);
            opacity: 0.2;
            z-index: -10;
        }

        .banner:before {
            height: 50%;
            top: -50px;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `background-size` property by setting a `background` property right after. Use `background-image` instead.

So instead of:

```css
.banner:after {
    background-size: contain;
    background: url(../images/MobileBannerPANG.jpg);
}
```

Use:

```css
.banner:after {
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(../images/MobileBannerPANG.jpg);
}
```

Do this for the ones in `@media` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's something to do with background-size. instead cover, try contain,auto or other available options until you get what you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different images, below and over 1199px:

>  1199px: https://www.poggenamp.com/images/BANNERPGC.jpg

<= 1199px: https://www.poggenamp.com/images/MobileBannerPANG.jpg

```css
.banner:after {
    content: "";
    background: url(../images/BANNERPGC.jpg) center no-repeat;
    height: 50vh;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    /* ... */
    .banner:after {
        background-size: contain;
        background: url(../images/MobileBannerPANG.jpg);
    }
}
```

Comparing the content of the two images, the displayed sizes of the items in the images differ at the switching point 1199px you get the scaling jump of the background.

You also have a position jump when it switches.

One possibility to solve this is to change the definition:

```css
.banner:after {
    content: "";
    /* background: url(../images/BANNERPGC.jpg) center no-repeat; */

    background-image: url(../images/BANNERPGC.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: auto 100vh;

    height: 50vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: -10;
}
/* ... */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    /* ... */
    .banner:after {
        background-size: auto 100vh;
        background: url(../images/MobileBannerPANG.jpg);
    }
}
```

As the "mobile" edition of the picture is a centered crop  of the horizontal edges (and scaled down) the `center` will fit both images at 1199px. – But the width of the mobile picture should get at least a width of 1199px.